# Symlink "Permission denied"

Tags: linux, symlink

I am unable to find any existing questions addressing this:

I have a symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www  adm    49 Aug 26 10:00 pictures -> /home/user/foo/bar/baz
```

Target directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 www adm 4096 Aug 26 07:53 baz
```

Trying to access it as user www fails:

```
~$ sudo -u www ls /var/www/pictures
ls: cannot access /var/www/pictures: Permission denied
```

What on earth?

EDIT: Turns out the problem was missing permissions on outer folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `www` simply does not have access to `/home/user/foo/bar/baz`.

Check this and add proper access rights to this directory.

Comment: How can you tell that www does not have access to baz? It is owned by www. So is the parent folder "bar".

Comment: @DennisThrysøe: what about `foo`, `user`, and `home`?:)

Comment: No permissions there. So I guess that's the problem. Changing the question into "How can I symlink into a nested directory, within otherwise permission restricted directories". This is actually about sharing a single folder from a Dropbox managed hierarchy with another user. That's gotta be possible? :)

Comment: Interesting problem. I wonder what would happen if you have mounted `bar` or `baz` in another location with `mount -o bind`. This should help, but I cannot try it now. No other ideas at this moment.